# How to sync Yahoo Mail with OS X?

Tags: macos, data-synchronization, email, yahoo

Ever since I moved to a MacBook Air from a PC about two weeks ago, I have had a problem in syncing my Yahoo Sent Mail on my MacBook Air with my iPad and iPHone. What gets synced is some old sent mail going back from 2010, rather than the latest.

How can this be rectified?

Comment: Welcome to AskDifferent! There are actually two questions here, this site works better if you ask only one thing in a question. I've removed the second question, feel free to revise the edit and/or ask a new question for the second topic.

Comment: Xerxes, do the sent messages appear in the Sent Items folder in your Yahoo webmail?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is likely to be that Yahoo Mail runs on POP3 normally as opposed to IMAP. Without going through all the technical details all you really need to know is that POP is all about the Server talking to you in one direction, your mail client isn't talking back, whereas IMAP is a two way street - as in, when you delete something in your mail client, it gets deleted on the server.

SO, what has likely happened is you were running a mail client on your PC (like outlook probably), and when you delete mail that you've red or sent etc. or clear out any of your folders, it only deletes the mail on your PC, not on the server, and all your old messages are still there. What this means is a significant anti-clutter session may be necessary on your end of things.

To solve the problem for future, there is a way to setup IMAP mail transfer with Yahoo Mail, but rather than ramble on here I'm just gonna give you a link to [this youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xDr_pHHB5js) which will show you how to set it up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yahoo (somewhat quietly) introduced IMAP servers a while ago at imap.mail.yahoo.com.

Comment: Or, you could use Yahoo POP mail. I find POP easier to manage than IMAP.

Comment: Yeah, yahoo added IMAP servers, but as you say "rather quietly" because they were still trying to get people to pay for IMAP access.

Comment: Although I can understand why you would not want to write the instructions down in your post. One of the reasons for including something of them is because just using links and say look here can be broken. As is the one you use in your post..